# Make laptop boot to external monitor

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, dell-studio

Dell 1737
    2x Dell U2311H

The laptop lid is always closed and is wall mounted behind the monitors.

Every time i boot the laptop, i have to open the lid a little until it goes to the win 7 logon screen. Once there, i close the lid and both monitors get detected and the laptop screen switches off.

As the laptop is wall mounted how ever, its really tedious to keep opening and closing the lid.

Is there any way i can make it default to the external monitors permanently?

Any suggestions are welcome, even hardware mods. Im willing to rip apart the laptop to install a switch or something if needs be lol

Comment: I believe most dells have a hardware switch for mode for how the signal is treated (something like fn+F4). It can either be only to the laptop monitor, sent to both laptop and external monitor, or just external monitor. Try setting it just to go to the external monitor.

Comment: that switch does work but it isnt permanent, requires me to press the key combo every boot upm is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: Not sure on a dell, I just assumed it would retain the setting as I have the same feature on my HP laptop and it stays permanent.

Answer (score 1):

in certain BIOSes, there are settings to choose which monitor to use by default - usually External or LCD.

Try looking through your Dell 1737 for such a setting. Also, you can just plug out the monitor cable to and from your dell and it should auto-detect your external monitor and switch over.

Comment: the bios is very limited on the laptop... im thankful i can edit boot devices ¬_¬

i cant find any settings that are even remotly related to external monitors/video

iv looked into hacked bioses but cannot find any for my dell and dont wanna risk bricking it :S